# How To Merge Parallel Axios GET Requests and Promise allSettled Function With Source Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I can successfully resolve parallel execution of Axios GET requests using the allSettled Promise method. However, I can not merge the keys of the source object that contains the URL with the results of the GET request.

So, I have an array of objects that contains the URL I want to perform GET requests on, as well as some other info that I want to keep. This looks like the following:

```
 const axios = require('axios');

 const sources =[
  {
    name: 'Source1',
    url: 'https://run.mocky.io/v3/15ce0aa4-96b4-4af7-9252-b66b271cd73f'
  },
  {
    name: 'Source2',
    url: 'https://run.mocky.io/v3/a5a46911-3ad0-4342-a1a1-f753ea3f2241'
  }];

async function run() {

 const tasks = sources.map(source => axios.get(source.url));
 const results = await Promise.allSettled(tasks);
 const fulfilled = results.filter(result => result.status === 'fulfilled');

 console.log(fulfilled);
}

run();
```

Running the above code the fulfilled variable will be an array of fulfilled Promise outcome objects. That object looks approximately like:

```
 {
    status: 'fulfilled',
    value: {
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      data: ‘DATA FROM THE AXIOS GET REQUEST IS ADDED HERE’
  },
```

I want to include the ‘name’ key and value pair from my original sources array objects in each fulfilled promise object.

So, to be clear I want the following to be returned (notice the ‘name’ key’).

```
 {
    status: 'fulfilled',
    value: {
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      data: ‘DATA FROM THE AXIOS GET REQUEST IS ADDED HERE’,
      name: ‘Source1’ // I want this added from the original source object.
  },
```

I have not found a way to achieve this prior to the allSettled method being reached. Ideally, I’d like to do this inside the map function. However, if I return an object with a key with its value set as the axios GET request, it does not resolve and remains in pending status even after allSettled marks the overall request as fulfilled.

```
const tasks = sources.map(source => axios.get(source.url));
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing only `source.url`, pass the whole `source` object. Axios will take this as its `config` object.

Then, you will find this object copied in `response.config`.

```
async function run() {

     const tasks = sources.map(axios.get); // Passing the whole { url : "..." , name : "Source2" } as "config". This syntax is equivalent to sources.map(source => axios.get(sources))
    const responses = await Promise.allSettled(tasks);
    
    let results = responses.map( response => {
        let result = response.data;
        result.name = response.config.name; // <-- here
        return result;
    })


    const fulfilled = results.filter(result => result.status === 'fulfilled');

    console.log(fulfilled);
}
```

EDIT

I'm not 100% sure about the `axios` syntax though, according to the doc, it can be `axios(config)` or `axios.get(url, config)`. You can try `const tasks = sources.map(axios);` or `const tasks = sources.map(source => axios.get(sources.url, source));`

Comment: Yep, that did it. axios.get(source.url, source) as the return value was the answer. :-)